# Maintaining relationships in JPA 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I've been using JPA 2.0 for a while but, sad to admit, I haven't had enough time to learn it properly. It seems like I lack the basics of how to work with Entity Manager.

Moving one step at a time, I'd like to first ask you about maintaining relationships between mapped entities. Of course I know how to create mappings between entities, different types of available associations (`OneToOne`, etc.) and how databases work in general. I'm purely focused on maintaining it via `Entity Manager`, so please do not send me to any kind of general knowledge tutorial :-).

**The questions are:**

1. Am I right that as a programmer I'm responsible for maintaining (creating/updating/removing) relationships between instances of entities?
2. Do I have to always update (set to null, remove from collection, etc.) instances by hand?
3. Plain SQL can set entities to NULL on deleting, but it seems like JPA can't do such a simple thing. It also seems like a burden to do it manually. Is there a way to achieve that with JPA?
4. If I have `OneToMany` relationship and set to NULL the entity on the `Many` side of the relationship. Then I persist the changes in a Set by saving the entity on the `One` side. Do I then have to update the entities in the `Many` side and set association to NULL in each instance? Seems pure silliness for one-directional bindings!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need to investigate is the different options you have when mapping on entity. For example in the next piece of code the cascade all option will instruct jpa to delete the child list when the parent is deleted.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Child> events = new HashSet<Child>();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.  You maintain the object tree and modify it to look like what
   you want.
2. Yes and no.  If you want the entity to reference null, then yes. 
   For instance, if you are removing one Entity, then you should clean
   up any references to it held by other entities that you are not
   removing.  A practical example: its good practice to let an Employee
   know his/her Manager has been let go.  If the Employee is going to
   stay, it should either have its manager reference nulled out or set
   to a different manager, before the current manager can be removed.
   If the employee is going to be removed as well, then cascade remove
   can cascade to all the Manager's subordinates, in which case you do
   not need to clean up their references to the manager - as they are
   going away too.
3. I don't quite understand what SQL is setting to null.  Deleting
   removes the row in the database, so there isn't anything to set to
   null.  Cleaning up a reference shouldn't be that difficult in the
   object model, as JPA has a number of events to help such as
   preremove preupdate etc.  In the end though, the problem is with
   your java objects.  They are just java objects, so if you want
   something done, your application will need to do it for the most
   part. JPA handles building them and pushing them to the database,
   not changing the state for you.
4. Yes and no.  If you set up a bidirectional relationship, you must
   maintain both sides as mentioned above.  If you set the child's
   parent reference to null, you should let the parent know it no
   longer has a child, wouldn't you?  Your parent will continue to
   reference its child for as long as that Parent instance exists.  So
   even though the database is updated/controlled through the side that
   owns a relationship, the object model will be out of synch with the
   database until it is refreshed or somehow reloaded. JPA allows for
   multiple levels of caching, so it all depends on your provider setup
   how long that Parent instance will exist referencing a Child that no
   longer exists in the database.

Comment: In point 4 I meant to ask about the following: I want to remove the link between the `Parent` entity and it's `Children`. In my code I fetch the `Parent` and clear set the children to `EMPTY_SET`. Then I save the `Parent`. For me that ought to be enough, but how to properly cleanup the other side of a link? Should I iterate over children first, set `parent` to `null` and `em.persist(child)`? I would imagine `em` being clever enough to understand what I did and clean up those references automatically! Can you elaborate?

Comment: It depends on what you want to happen.  If the children should not exist without a parent, either associate it to a new parent or set the orphan removal flag and JPA will delete the children when they are dereferenced.  If you want them to exist independently, you need to tell them what their current state should be, and of course, merge it.  Some providers (EclipseLink) may still have legacy EJB2.0 code that can handle nulling out the other side for you.  This relationship maintenance caused more problems than it was worth, and was intentionally excluded from the JPA spec.

Comment: If calling merge on each pruned child is an issue, there are a number of approaches you can use.  A simple one would be to store pruned objects in a collection that isn't persisted, that you then use in a preupdate event method on the parent. This method would go through the list fixing and merging as needed.